# How Dynamically link assets in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm new to Laravel 5 i while searching over internet i for some basic concepts i found that in Laravel we can link assets dynamically i didn't understand how can we link them dynamically.

How can we know that an asset is used in certain point and include it in the view.

As per my knowledge i'm writing all the assets in one blade template and extending in views.

example.blade.php

```
{{Html::Style('somefile')}}
{{Html::script('somefile')}}
```

custom view.blade.php

```
@extends('example)
```

But how come this do Dynamically?

Comment: Could you please explain this? I am not getting what do you want to say.

Comment: Actually, you need to provide your code, and the issue you are facing, so we can help on that.

Comment: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/dynamically-link-assets

Answer (score 1):

In main template layout.blade.php, you have common includes:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ... common JS/CSS

    @yield('css')
    @yield('js')
</head>
```

in custom page template custom.blade.php, where you extend main template you can add **dynamically** additional CSS or JS by adding sections:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

    {{-- dynamic JS/CSS definitions --}}
    @section('css')
        {{Html::Style('some new CSS file only for this template')}}
    @endsection

    @section('js')
        {{Html::script('some new JS file only for this template')}}
    @endsection

@section('content')
    Your custom page content
@endsection
```

Read more about [blade sections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-a-layout).

Answer (score 0):

- Add css file public/css/admin.css  and Add js file
  public/js/jquery.min.js

Include css

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/admin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Include js

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```